# Delete cell if it doesn't contain a keyword

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column that contains directories.

How can I search for cells that don't contain a keyword and remove them?

For example, if I have a column like this:

```
C:\Users\Desktop\Folder\html\test.html
C:\Users\Desktop\Folder\book.html
C:\Users\Desktop\Folder\Documents\test.html
C:\Users\Desktop\Folder\frontpage.html
C:\Users\Desktop\Folder\test.html
```

And I want to search for the keyword "test.html", I should end up with this:

```
C:\Users\Desktop\Folder\html\test.html
C:\Users\Desktop\Folder\Documents\test.html
C:\Users\Desktop\Folder\test.html
```

The 2nd and 4th lines should be deleted.

I found something that works, but takes a long time to finish if I check the entire column (so I just use 100).

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim ContainWord As String

Set rng = Range("A1:A100")

ContainWord = "keyword"

For Each cell In rng.Cells
If cell.Find(ContainWord) Is Nothing Then cell.Clear
Next cell
```

Comment: processing takes time. Like range 1 to 10 is different than 1 to 65535. If that data was in memory in C# then your performance would be markedly different than running code through COM components that extend the functionality of excel to external programming interfaces. Or in your case, an amazing application (Excel) that layers on a not so fast programming paradigm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
Set rng = Range("A1:A100")
```

with:

```
Set Rng = Intersect(Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it should be faster:

```
With UsedRange
    .AutoFilter 1, "<>*test.html*", xlAnd, , False
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
End With
```

Comment: turn the `AutoFilter` off at the end, so user can actually see their results! :)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman thanks for the advice, but in fact in my test everything becomes visible at the end, due to the `VisibleDropDown:=False` parameter ;) I tried both but I like the last, shorter way. I leave the finalization to the OP anyway.